# composer autoload error

Tags: php, composer-php, package

I'm trying to work with composer and will create own packages. My package project has the following file structure:

```
scr/Scheduler.php
.gitignore
composer.json
```

The test class:

```
namespace david\Scheduler;

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

class Scheduler
{
    private $yamlParser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->yamlParser = new Parser();
    }
}
```

and the composer.json file

```
...
"require": {
    "symfony/yaml": "~3.0.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "david\\Scheduler\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

That all I've committed to a private github repository. Currently I've only the master branch and no tags.
My second step was to create a client project with the following composer.json file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "david/scheduler",
            "type": "package",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "git@github.com:david/scheduler.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "david/scheduler": "dev-master"
}
```

When I'm running composer update the github project will be cloned and stored in the vendor directory. But only my package. The dependency to the symfony/yaml will not loaded.

```
vendor
    composer
    david/scheduler
```

Also composer create a empty autoload_psr4 file.

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
);
```

I think maybe there are some issues in my architecture...

Comment: Can you show the way you register the private repository in the main project ? you can obfuscate the URL to keep it private

Comment: @ChristopheCoevoet I've updated the composer.json snippet. Also I added the following line to the description: `Currently I've only the master branch and no tags.`

Comment: I assume that you added the `repositories` section in the wrong part of the code snippet (as it does not make sense to reference `david/scheduler` inside the `david/scheduler` repo). I answered below based on this.

Comment: @ChristopheCoevoet oh yes. Copy and paste fail. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are registering your custom repository using a `package` type, which means that the root package is defining the metadata of `david/scheduler` and the composer.json file in the git repo is never used by Composer. and in this package definition, there is no dependency on the `symfony/yaml` component and no autoloading for your Scheduler class.

As a general rule, the `package` repository should always be considered as a last resort (it has many drawbacks). when you control the git repository, putting a composer.json file in the repository and using a `vcs` repository works much better (as composer can then rely on metadata coming from git itself, and the package metadata are provided in the package git repo).

The root package should look like this:

```js
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:david/scheduler.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "david/scheduler": "dev-master"
    }
}
```